# How to make Visual Studio Code forward caught keystrokes?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-code

Some keystrokes are caught by Visual Studio Code (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> for instance in my case), thus preventing the built-in terminal to receive it.
How could I make Visual Studio Code forward such a keystroke (and possibly others that could get caught)?

I'd also like to be able to use VSC shortcuts involving it and therefore to be able to still catch it when I want.

---

For comparison, Tmux with default settings will forward a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> stroke by doubling it (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>).

For instance, despite Tmux catching my first <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>, I'm still able to make my irssi session get a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> by making a second stroke in order to put my text in **bold**. But I'm also still able use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> for interacting with tmux itself. That's the kind of behavior I'm seeking with Visual Studio Code.

Comment: What's the value of your `terminal.integrated.sendKeybindingsToShell`?

Comment: `terminal.integrated.sendKeybindingsToShell` is unchecked (`False`) for me. Checking it/Setting it to `True` makes VSC pass some keystrokes to the terminal that weren't before (CTRL+F for instance) but not every one (CTRL+K).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the current version, you can:

- enable `terminal.integrated.sendKeybindingsToShell` - this will send most keybinds to the shell, some of them are still skipped.
- edit `terminal.integrated.commandsToSkipShell` - there you can set commands which are and aren't sent to shell specifically. It's overriden by the option above. E.g. to disable mentioned <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> by default, you can use `-workbench.action.toggleSidebarVisibility`:

  ```
  "terminal.integrated.commandsToSkipShell": [
    // Minus at the start means it should go through
    "-workbench.action.toggleSidebarVisibility"
  ]
  ```

The problem with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> is that it's used by a lot of commands as a chord. You could disable `terminal.integrated.allowChords` setting to get rid of chords overall, which this setting also mentions as something you should do for these kind of shortcuts to work:

> Note that when setting this to true and the keystroke results in a chord it will bypass Terminal > Integrated: Commands To Skip Shell, setting this to false is particularly useful when you want ctrl+k to go to your shell (not VS Code)

You can read more about these [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/terminal/advanced).

Unbinding/rebinding all chords which have a combination that starts with your desired keybind (e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> -> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>) should also normally work and I'm pretty sure that's all you can try.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
Sadly your suggestions precisely aren't what I'm searching for (as it implies renouncing to being able to chose where to send those keystrokes on the fly). Yet I guess it's the best answer I'll get since you stated "it's all I can try".
I'll perhaps make an issue on vscode github if it's not already done by someone else.